# Jquery datatable footercallback not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I need to show the summation of column's value in table's footer.I used jquery data table plugin for it. For summation, I'm using the footer callback functionality.It is not working.I'm getting an error like this **TypeError: f is undefined**.This I got from here https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data_table_with_footer').DataTable( {
    " footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
      var api = this.api(), data;

       // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
       var intVal = function ( i ) {
          return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
       };

     // Total over all pages
     total = api.column( 2 ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
       return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );

     // Total over this page
     pageTotal = api
        .column( 2, { page: 'current'} )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );

     // Update footer
     $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
        '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
     );
   }
 } );
} );
```

Here, My ruby on rails code:

```
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover data_table_with_footer" >     
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Site</th>
                  <th>No.of Files Uploaded</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                <% @dependent_data_upload_success.each do |data|%>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= data.site %></td>
                    <td class="files_uploaded_count"><%= data.files_count %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Are you aware that your data set has not 5 columns, like in the example from datatables.net, but only 2? You'd have to adjust your calculations to that fact, since `api.column(4)` is not referring to a real column object.

Comment: I tried api.column( 2 ) but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Use `footerCallback:` instead of `" footerCallback":` - this is why quoted properties is so dangerous to use, they are merely a source of errors and completely unnessecary..

Comment: `api.column(2)` also does not exist. You have indices starting at 0. Also, adjust the `colspan` of your first footer `th`.